# All my work has been deleted by git control, howto restore?

Tags: visual-studio, github

im developing a private c++ tool for month now. And now everything seems to be lost because i wanted to use Github. I really hope that i can restore it with someones help.

**What i did:**

a few weeks ago i played around with github in Visual studio. I was able to commit a lot of files to my private Github. I dont know how Github works in detail so please be patient.

After that i just did not use it anymore as i just wanted to know how it might work for a later step.

I started recoding a lot of stuff and changing almost everything on my tool. Today i wanted to commit those new coded project to the github repository.

I thought about deleting the current github content bforehand and did it so .. so i went on github.com and just deteled my "test commit" from weeks ago.

After that i went back to Visual studio and tryed to commit my new project. That it started to pull and push or something and after that everything what was "new" has been deleted.

Please tell me, am i able to restore my project in any way ? I really start to cry if all my work is lost.

Thank you

EDIT:

**D:\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos>git log --oneline**

```
4c6b7d4 (HEAD -> master) Revert "Delete myAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"
4ac3277 Revert "Delete myAPI/ImageRecognition directory"
49c9309 Revert "Delete CellMode/CellModedirectory"
6edabb4 Revert "Delete myAPI/myAPI directory"
c14b3d6 Revert "Delete myAPI directory"

315a581 (origin/master) Delete myAPI directory
ae8480c Delete myAPI/myAPI directory
d470468 Delete myAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory
49b3902 Delete CellMode/CellModedirectory
1cc00db Delete myAPI/ImageRecognition directory
```

**D:ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos>git log**

```
...

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: Me@mail.com
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory

commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory

commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50
Author: my@mail.de
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory

commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:35 2021 +0200
:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory

commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:35 2021 +0200

:...skipping...
commit 4c6b7d4e5f7d4f578d85115603f50618a089e024 (HEAD -> master)
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:34 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"

    This reverts commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19.

commit 4ac327770133159230385e087406bc54fc405d46
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:29:17 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"

    This reverts commit 1cc00dba2c4e9fb493f3da67a947311952b27a1c.

commit 49c93098a23fa45e0fd5cac3e24d7080e89e7436
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:45 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"

    This reverts commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da.

commit 6edabb44d6a754a69ce08fcf91d756034d47536b
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:28:18 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50.

commit c14b3d6cfd7a126d8f983400b6cb7f385eb61754
Author: My@mail.com
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:27:59 2021 +0200

    Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"

    This reverts commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae.

commit 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae (origin/master)
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:45 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI directory

commit ae8480c541496c0d107fbbe0ad4cc73c10c4cb50
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:35 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory

commit d4704683e2f410b618e2c27f28904f3e0d36ae19
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:26 2021 +0200

    Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory

commit 49b390248a34dfb738d343d15e11a37b79f208da
Author: my@mail.de
Date:   Wed Jun 9 17:04:14 2021 +0200
```

EDIT2:

**D:\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos>git --no-pager log --pretty=reference --after=2021-04-01**

```
4c6b7d4 (Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory", 2021-06-09)
4ac3277 (Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory", 2021-06-09)
49c9309 (Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory", 2021-06-09)
6edabb4 (Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory", 2021-06-09)
c14b3d6 (Revert "Delete MyAPI directory", 2021-06-09)
315a581 (Delete MyAPI directory, 2021-06-09)
ae8480c (Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory, 2021-06-09)
d470468 (Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory, 2021-06-09)
49b3902 (Delete CellMode/CellMode directory, 2021-06-09)
1cc00db (Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory, 2021-06-09)
b173621 (framework header, 2021-05-27)
1a57ac4 (pch files, 2021-05-27)
332d989 (libs, 2021-05-26)
ac63482 (Start Commit, 2021-05-26)
d47a27e (start, 2021-05-26)
```

**D:\Davy\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos>git --no-pager reflog --after=2021-04-01**

```
4c6b7d4 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
4c6b7d4 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{1}: revert: Revert "Delete MyAPI/HTTPCurlWrapper directory"
4ac3277 HEAD@{2}: revert: Revert "Delete MyAPI/ImageRecognition directory"
49c9309 HEAD@{3}: revert: Revert "Delete CellMode/CellMode directory"
6edabb4 HEAD@{4}: revert: Revert "Delete MyAPI/MyAPI directory"
c14b3d6 HEAD@{5}: revert: Revert "Delete MyAPI directory"
315a581 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to 315a5816b08dd662237d28f09aa70cb0ea975bae
d6f7f2a HEAD@{7}: commit: Initial Commit
b173621 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to master
b173621 HEAD@{9}: commit: framework header
1a57ac4 HEAD@{10}: commit: pch files
332d989 HEAD@{11}: commit: libs
ac63482 HEAD@{12}: commit: Start Commit
d47a27e HEAD@{13}: commit: start
af4d81e HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from master to master
af4d81e HEAD@{15}: initial pull
```

Comment: _"I thought about deleting the current github content bforehand"_ that's not what one usually does with a git repository. Do you know what **git** is and what it's used for (**not** github)? If not I really recommend reading up on the core concepts or watching a tutorial on youtube. Also I'd never delete commits or change history from within github (I didn't even know this was possible), use either the command line or a graphical tool, like [fork](https://git-fork.com) or the built-in gitk. But please please go ahead and read up on the core concepts of git.

Comment: For now can you please describe what's still on your local machine? Open cmd or powershell and go into the root directory of your git repository (where the .git folder is located, usually the directory of the .sln file). Then run `git log` (or `git log --oneline` for a short overview) and `git reflog` and see if your commit is mentioned anywhere. You can update your question so it contains the output of both commands, **but make sure you remove personal or sensitive data from the output first**.

Comment: @Timo thank you for trying to help. I edited my initial post. What i really dont understand is, there was one new Project "CellModeGUI" which i created and linked to my Overall Project. This Project "CellModeGUI" is completly lost, its also not listed in any log. All files (Headers, and Sources) i selected for the commit, just have been delted or something.

Also the files/projects mentiond in the git logs above are all the "old" ones from weeks ago. The new ones i wanted to bring to my github repository are also lost and not mentioned in any log.

Comment: Your log still contains personal data. You should edit the question again and this time just use the output from `git --no-pager log --pretty=reference --after=2021-04-01`. That will print a short log from April to now. Also please post the output from `git --no-pager reflog --after=2021-04-01`. These outputs shouldn't contain personal data in the first place (unless you have sensitive commit messages).

Comment: Also `D:\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos`, is that the location of your repository? Do you have a single repository for all your projects? Usually a repository is specific to a project. For example, if you have a project called "Tetris" (and by project I mean the whole thing that you're building, **not** a Visual Studio project), I'd expect the repository to be at `D:\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos\Tetris`.

Comment: @Timo thanks, yes D:\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repos is the path to my repository and it holds all my projects but i only was commiting 1 of them "CellMode" and the linked ones to this project. (i updated my Post with the new commands you told me). What im still wondering is, that my Project "CellModeGUI" is not shown anywhere but the as mentioned before, headers/source files and the CellModeGUI.sln file has been removed/deleted.

Comment: The path just has been created while i was playing around with github and Visual studio. I did not use github before and did not know that it should be "per project". So for the next projects ill split it up per project thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233568/discussion-between-timo-and-dvy-hrnsch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright after a short chat we were able to recover the deleted files. Here are some points to follow that this doesn't happen again in the future:

- Use one git repository for each of your projects.
- Never delete files from within github. Just delete them locally. Git will notice that and you can commit those deletions like any other changes to your files.
- Commit and push on a regular basis, not only once every month. Commits are basically little recovery points that you can go back to if you mess something up.
- Please read up on how git works and what commits and branches are.
- Configure your Visual Studio to not automagically perform destructive git actions (not sure how this happened in the first place, this is definitely not the default setting).

Comment: basically saved my life :-) thank you again and I’ll setup my Visual studio now correctly.